# Single Logout second request fails in ADFS

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs

I have setup when I'm using Auth0 to SSO through ADFS into a Spring Security Application, using saml all the way through. So, it looks like this:

```
Auth0 ----> ADFS ----> SpringSecurity App.
```

I have control of Auth0, but it's simulating a third party that would integrate with our ADFS server.

This works fine.

To do logout, I minimally want to destroy the sessions on the SpringSecurity App and the ADFS application.  When I call logout the first time, a SAML logout request gets passed to ADFS.  ADFS then passes a Logout request to Auth0, where it ends.  This destroys the session.

However, if, without closing the browser, I SSO in again and then logout, ADFS rejects the logout request with a `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester`, meaning it didn't like something about my request.

I've been able to narrow it down to the fact that there is a `SAMLLogout` cookie, with a domain of my ADFS server set.  This appears to be set when the logout bounces over to Auth0, but is never removed. Calling logout when that cookie is present causes an error.  When I delete that one cookie, I can logout successfully (in that it destroys the ADFS session and sends a logout request to Auth0).  The cookie has a `Session` expiration, so closing and opening the browser also works.

I can post token requests and responses, but I don't think it has to do with the tokens itself. They are all signed correctly, and ADFS doesn't report any errors when doing the logout.

I don't necessarily need ADFS to call out to Auth0 (or any IdP) to destroy that session, I simply need it to destroy it's own session.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using destroy kindly use "unset" to avoid further problems with regards to your log out code. I don't know why but there are times that "destroy" causes problems with regards to log out button.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't literally mean some call to "destroy" or "unset", I meant more the built in functionality of Spring Security and ADFS

Answer (score 0):

We came up with the following solution:
we have noticed that the adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx page has the "Sign out from all the sites that you have accessed." option that will kill the authentication cookies no matter how many times you logged in and logged out from different tabs.
We have create a duplicate copies of the idpinitiatedsignon.aspx and the idpinitiatedsignon.aspx.cs and renamed them (example logoutpage.aspx).
We have added the SingleLogout(); at the end of the Page_Init of the idpinitiatedsignon.aspx.cs so it reads:
protected void Page_Init( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        string rpIdentity = Context.Request.QueryString[RpIdentityQueryParameter];

```
    //
    // If the query string specified a certain relying party, sign in to that relying party.
    //
    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( rpIdentity ) )
    {
        string decodedIdentity = Server.UrlDecode( rpIdentity );

        if ( decodedIdentity == IdpAsRpIdentifier )
        {
            decodedIdentity = String.Empty;
        }

        SignIn( rpIdentity, new SignOnRequestParameters() );
    }
    else
    {
        PopulateConditionalVisibilityControls();

        RelyingPartyDropDownList.DataSource = RelyingParties;
        RelyingPartyDropDownList.DataBind();

        UpdateText();
    }
SingleLogout();
}
```

then we referenced this new page example logoutpage.aspx as the logout URL.
I hope this will save some research time for others who are facing this SAML Logout issue on ADFS v2.